# For loops to iterate through only those files that are available

Tags: bash, unix

Say I have monthly data files for Jan 2020 and all of 2019 and I want to loop through all the available months to perform some action. This is my closest attempt

```
for month in {01..12}; do
    for year in 2019 2020; do
        cat this_file-${year}-${month} | grep this_word -i
    done
done
```

It works in the sense that I can see the output for 13 months, but then also returns "no such file or directory" for all the months in 2020 except Jan (because that's the only month I have the data file for in 2020), which makes copying output directly from the terminal a pain. Any pointers?

Because I run my commands on the shell, a one liner solution would be perfect.

Comment: First, don't use `cat`. `grep` can open the file itself, or read from standard input via a redirection. Second, you can always check if the file exists before using it: `[ -f this_file ] || continue`. (I assume `this_file` is constructed from the values of `year` and `month`.)

Comment: `grep -i this_word this_file-20{19,20}-{01..12} 2>&-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With brace expansion you could do:

```
grep -i 'this_word' file-{2019..2020}-{01..12} 2>/dev/null
```

The error messages are suppressed by redirecting stderr to `/dev/null`.

Comment: Note that this will have problems above some amount of filenames.

Comment: @jhnc Thanks for the note, I'll keep that in mind. This works for what I am working with.

Comment: @Freddy I typically cat the file to explore some of its content and then grep on something specific. Is it possible to rewrite this by starting with cat, then filename with brace expansion, then a grep and then end with the  stderr redirection?

Comment: @Freddy You should probably add the `-h` option to `grep` to keep it from printing filenames.

Comment: @Gandalf `cat` (or `more` or `less` or...) is reasonable for reading the files yourself, but it's a waste to use it with `grep` because `grep` is perfectly capable of reading from files all by itself. This is what's called a [useless use of `cat`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat) (UUOC for short).

Comment: @Gandalf You could use `cat file-{2019..2020}-{01..12} 2>/dev/null | grep -i 'this_word'` if you still want to omit the error messages for non-existing files. Sure, it's a useless `cat`, but it's easier to edit the `grep` pattern.

Comment: @Freddy Also you'll still get error messages from grep, which is a plus.

Comment: Using `grep -s ...` is better than `grep ... 2>/dev/null`. It will suppress errors about files, but still show other errors e.g. for invalid regex patterns. At least for GNU/POSIX grep; other grep implemenations might not have `-s` or it might behave differently.

Comment: @wjandrea That should work with any POSIX-compliant `grep`. According to [the standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html#tag_20_55_04): "**`-s`**
Suppress the error messages ordinarily written for nonexistent or unreadable files. Other error messages shall not be suppressed."

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for month in {01..12}; do
    for year in 2019 2020; do
        f="this_file-${year}-${month}"
        [[ -f $f ]] && grep this_word -i "$f"
    done
done
```

There is no need to use `cat "$f"` and a pipe.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix is to just check if the file exists:

```
for month in {01..12}; do
    for year in 2019 2020; do
        file="this_file-${year}-${month}"
        if [[ -f $file ]]; then
            grep this_word -i "$file"
        fi
    done
done
```

Also you don't need `cat` when `grep` can open the file itself.